# File ended while scanning use of \algocf@Fnmain \input{..}

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, pseudocode

I get compilation error with an unhelpful error message when I compile the below pseudocode written using algorithm2e package.
Here's my error message

"File ended while scanning use of \algocf@Fnmain \input{chapters/4_lan}"

```
\usepackage[vlined,ruled]{algorithm2e}
%% optional fonts and color configuration
\SetAlFnt{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\ArgSty{\normalfont\ttfamily}
\renewcommand\KwSty[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{\ttfamily#1}}\unskip}
\SetAlCapFnt{\normalfont\ttfamily\large}
\renewcommand\AlCapNameFnt{\ttfamily\large}
% vertical rules in cyan color
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\algocf@Vline}[1]{%     no vskip in between boxes but a strut to separate them, 
  \strut\par\nointerlineskip% then interblock space stay the same whatever is inside it
  \algocf@push{\skiprule}%        move to the right before the vertical rule
  \hbox{\bgroup\color{cyan}\vrule\egroup%
    \vtop{\algocf@push{\skiptext}%move the right after the rule
      \vtop{\algocf@addskiptotal #1}\bgroup\color{cyan}\Hlne\egroup}}\vskip\skiphlne% inside the block
  \algocf@pop{\skiprule}%\algocf@subskiptotal% restore indentation
  \nointerlineskip}% no vskip after
%
\renewcommand{\algocf@Vsline}[1]{%    no vskip in between boxes but a strut to separate them, 
  \strut\par\nointerlineskip% then interblock space stay the same whatever is inside it
  \algocf@bblockcode%
  \algocf@push{\skiprule}%        move to the right before the vertical rule
  \hbox{\bgroup\color{cyan}\vrule\egroup%               the vertical rule
    \vtop{\algocf@push{\skiptext}%move the right after the rule
      \vtop{\algocf@addskiptotal #1}}}% inside the block
  \algocf@pop{\skiprule}% restore indentation
  \algocf@eblockcode%
}
%
\makeatother
\SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{}{}



\begin{algorithm}

\Fn{trackAndFilter (past, pointCloud)}{
 past $\leftarrow$ structure of vectors of centroids in past $n$ frames\;
 $n$ $\larrow$ size of past\;
 centroid $\in \big[x, y, z, match \big]$\;
 \For{$i$ from 1 to $n$ }{
   \For{$centroid1$ from past\big[i\big].begin to past\big[i\big].end}{
        \For{$centroid2$ from past[i-1].begin to past\big[i-1\big].end}{
            \If{distance between centroid1 and centroid2 $>$ 50cm}{
                $centroid1[match]$ $+=$ 1\;}
        }
        \If{$i>1$ AND $centroid1[match]$ $==$ 0}{
        \For{$j$ from i to 1}{
            \For{$centroid3$ from past\big[i-2\big].begin to past\big[i-1\big].end}{
                        \If{distance between centroid1 and centroid2 $>$ 50cm}{
                            $centroid1\big[match\big]$ $+=$ 1\;}
                    }
        \If{$centroid1\big[match\big]$ $>$ 0}{
            break\;}
        }
        }

        }
        \For{$centroid4$ from past[$n-1$].begin to past\big[$n-1$\big].end}{
            \If{$centroid4\big[match\big]$ $>$ 2}{
                pointCloud $\larrow$ $centroid4$\;
                }
        }
        past $\larrow$ pop out first vector\;
        }


\caption{Polling}
\end{algorithm}
```

What am I doing wrong? I made sure to put all math in math modes and escape special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket for your opening `\Fn`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[vlined,ruled]{algorithm2e}
%% optional fonts and color configuration
\SetAlFnt{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\ArgSty{\normalfont\ttfamily}
\renewcommand\KwSty[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{\ttfamily#1}}\unskip}
\SetAlCapFnt{\normalfont\ttfamily\large}
\renewcommand\AlCapNameFnt{\ttfamily\large}
% vertical rules in cyan color
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\algocf@Vline}[1]{%     no vskip in between boxes but a strut to separate them, 
  \strut\par\nointerlineskip% then interblock space stay the same whatever is inside it
  \algocf@push{\skiprule}%        move to the right before the vertical rule
  \hbox{\bgroup\color{cyan}\vrule\egroup%
    \vtop{\algocf@push{\skiptext}%move the right after the rule
      \vtop{\algocf@addskiptotal #1}\bgroup\color{cyan}\Hlne\egroup}}\vskip\skiphlne% inside the block
  \algocf@pop{\skiprule}%\algocf@subskiptotal% restore indentation
  \nointerlineskip}% no vskip after
%
\renewcommand{\algocf@Vsline}[1]{%    no vskip in between boxes but a strut to separate them, 
  \strut\par\nointerlineskip% then interblock space stay the same whatever is inside it
  \algocf@bblockcode%
  \algocf@push{\skiprule}%        move to the right before the vertical rule
  \hbox{\bgroup\color{cyan}\vrule\egroup%               the vertical rule
    \vtop{\algocf@push{\skiptext}%move the right after the rule
      \vtop{\algocf@addskiptotal #1}}}% inside the block
  \algocf@pop{\skiprule}% restore indentation
  \algocf@eblockcode%
}
%
\makeatother
\SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{}{}
\newcommand{\larrow}{\leftarrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \Fn{trackAndFilter (past, pointCloud)}{
    past $\leftarrow$ structure of vectors of centroids in past $n$ frames\;
    $n$ $\larrow$ size of past\;
    centroid $\in \big[x, y, z, match \big]$\;
    \For{$i$ from 1 to $n$ }{
      \For{$centroid1$ from past\big[i\big].begin to past\big[i\big].end}{
        \For{$centroid2$ from past[i-1].begin to past\big[i-1\big].end}{
          \If{distance between centroid1 and centroid2 $>$ 50cm}{
            $centroid1[match]$ $+=$ 1\;}
        }
        \If{$i>1$ AND $centroid1[match]$ $==$ 0}{
          \For{$j$ from i to 1}{
            \For{$centroid3$ from past\big[i-2\big].begin to past\big[i-1\big].end}{
              \If{distance between centroid1 and centroid2 $>$ 50cm}{
                $centroid1\big[match\big]$ $+=$ 1\;}
            }
            \If{$centroid1\big[match\big]$ $>$ 0}{
              break\;}
          }
        }
      }
      \For{$centroid4$ from past[$n-1$].begin to past\big[$n-1$\big].end}{
        \If{$centroid4\big[match\big]$ $>$ 2}{
          pointCloud $\larrow$ $centroid4$\;
        }
      }
      past $\larrow$ pop out first vector\;
    }
  }% <--- ...this was missing...
  \caption{Polling}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But now I'm getting this error on the line you added: Undefined control sequence }

Comment: @Jim: When you compile my example code (which we call a minimal working example, since I can copy-and-paste-and-compile) does it give you an error?

Comment: Nope. Yours works. Could it be because I'm using memoir instead of article like you did?

Comment: @Jim: When I switch out `article` for `memoir`, I don't get an error. You must be doing something different. Note that I had to also define `\newcommand{\larrow}{\leftarrow}`...